# How to ignore &nbsp; while searching for a text in web page using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the string from the excel sheet and want to check whether the string is present in web page or not. This is the code i'm trying,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "driver path");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(url);

        String ps = driver.getPageSource();
        File src = new File("excel path\\Data.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet Sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row = Sheet1.getRow(0);

        for (Row row : Sheet1) {
            String strtext=row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        if(ps.contains(strtext)) {

            System.out.println("TEXT is present");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("TEXT is not present");
        }
        }

    }

}
```

with this code I can able to get text from excel sheet and check whether the text is present in web page. But I have one issue here, Some text in web page contains &nbsp between texts. So when I tried to search those texts it says those texts are not present even though the texts are in the web page ie: For Example: If my text is "Easily share and collaborate with others by making edits" but in page source it is like "Easily share and collaborate with others&nbsp by&nbsp making edits" So even if the text present in web page it says like text is not present.I want to ignore &nbsp Can any one help me in this pls...

Comment: Why not add `ps = ps.replace("&nbsp","")`?

Comment: This question is related to selenium web element and you can't use java String function directly for the identification of web elements from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below project that I have already created. Actually alt+0160 with translate function of the xpath could help you resolve this. As you can see in the below code snippet second argument in the translate function is alt+0160. If you face any issue then please let me know.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W0aoCqEqp-SPBw_NH6IKbF-KQsXDMraH/view

```
//h3[contains(translate(text(),' ',' ' ), 'App-1 Playground Login')]
```

Comment: I have seen your project there you have used this Xpath for single heading so u have used translate function for that text . But actually in my case there are multiple texts so I'm looking for a single line of Xpath or some other functionality that ignores "&nbsp;" while searching for text in Web Page @Rapper AB